# Java profiling for scalability and time complexity

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling

I am working on a java application which has a producer-consumer pattern. Earlier the producer was not producing events in order (for example a '2' was produced before '1') but the consumer had to send them in order (for example,  '1' then '2' then '3' etc). To account for that A TreeSet was being used to maintain a queue and an in order traversal on the same was being done to peek and remove the elements. SO FAR SO GOOD. What has changed is that Producer now produces events in order, thus I have decided to use:-

a) a LinkedBlockingQueue (which has a fundamental property of a queue where in only first and last element can be accessed , as in a queue it should be).

b) using an LBQ has taken me to O(1) from an O(log n) in a treeset.

c) I no more have to write explicit synchronized, ReentrantLock takes care of that in put and take method of LBQ.

d) I no more have to write an explicit wait/notify, LBQ takes care of that.

e) LBQ has 2 locks, and hence a put and a take can take simultaneously on different CPUs.

f) LBQ uses CAS to maintain the queue of waiting threads.

ALL things seem well to me. But I am stuck, here are the following questions:-

a) I need to be able to prove the advantages of using an LBQ over a TreeSet, by collecting a few metrics. Which free profiler should I use with my eclipse to proceed ? Visual VM is fine but then is there any better option available ?(Introscope will be used in explicit runs of my application and not on my local eclipse, that's a constraint I can't fight, TPTP is rejected).

b) How do I prove the increase in throughput (which looks to be there on paper) because of the use of 2 locks in a LinkedBlockingQueue ? It's an important aspect I would want to see and prove.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you have looked at perf4j (along with its graphingstatistics appender) for measuring/displaying performance statistics (http://perf4j.codehaus.org/).  If not feasible for some reason, please share why as it would probably be useful.

Also, one can look at metrics (http://metrics.codahale.com/) as well as a combination of heapster & ostrich (if possible in your case) for heap/performance measurement (https://github.com/mariusaeriksen/heapster). With metrics, you can rely on either graphite or ganglia for display (if not using JMX).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will have a look and let u know for sure. But what metric would I measure to say that my application's throughput has increased ? Also have u used them with eclipse ?

Comment: Hi - its simpler if you're using maven (for either perf4j or codahale metrics).  For perf4j, you should be able to just download the jar file and proceed unless my memory is failing me.  For simple tests, using min/max/standard deviation/count (in graphical format where possible) would help your case when sharing it with others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use visual vm or the netbeans profiler if you want to visualize the memory/thread use .

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar load testing using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It can also (but I didn't do this) easily calculate [throughput](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html). In my case, I had to write a Java Request [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) Sampler, that acted as a client to my system under test. The Java Request Sampler's results can be easily [graphed](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results) by JMeter's listeners (and those do show throughput). It sounds like you may need to do the same. They do have out of the box samplers for TCP, HTTP, etc., though that you can maybe use.